# A bounded divergent sequence has at least two adherence values

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to solve the following problem from Lima's "Análise Real":

> If the real number $a$ is not the limit of the bounded sequence $(x_n)$, prove that some subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to a limit $b \neq a$.

Of course, if $(x_n)$ is convergent, then the result is obvious, since $(x_n)$ is a subsequence of itself which converges to a limit that is not $a$, by hypothesis. However, if $(x_n)$ is *not* convergent, then I understand I should prove there are at least two subsequences with different limits (so that, for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a subsequence that does not converge to $a$).

Since the sequence is bounded, it certainly has a convergent subsequence, but I don't know how to proceed from there. Why couldn't all the other subsequences converge to the same limit as well?

Comment: "Why couldn't all the other subsequences converge to the same limit as well?" Because then the sequence would be convergent

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you know that every bounded sequence has at least one convergent subsequence?

Comment: By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (every sequence has a monotone subsequence; if the sequence is bounded, then this monotone subsequence is also bounded, therefore it converges).

Answer (score 0):

***Given:*** The sequence is bounded and not convergent.

**Proof by Contradiction**

***Assume:*** All the subsequences of the sequence $x_n$ converge to $a$. If we run into any absurdity by making this assumption then it must be that atleast 2 subsequences of the seqeunce do not converge to the same thing.

**Rough Solution:**

We know our sequence isn't convergent to $a$. So, there exists some $ϵ > 0$ (we are specifically focusing on this $\epsilon$) for which for all $N$, there will always be some $n > N$ such that $|x_n - a| > \epsilon$. Here we just did the inverse of the definition of a convergent sequence. Lets just make a subsequence out of these specific points of the sequence.

Here we chose a sequence $N_n$ which is monotonically increasing. That is $N_1 < N_2 < ...$.

Now, we start picking elements one by one like $x_{n_1}$ for $n_1 > N_1$, $x_{n_2}$ for $n_2 > N_2$, and so on. Each with the property that $|x_{n_i} - a| > \epsilon$.

Now, this is definitely subsequece of $x_n$. And this subsequence never converges to $a$ since for the specific $\epsilon$ we chose at the start, no element of this subsequnce gets in the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $a$. Again this is the same $\epsilon$ we chose at the start.

**Hence** we not only contradicted our assumption of all subsequences converging to $a$ but also found the specific subsequence which doesn't converge to $a$.

Comment: We could have also proved this without the assumption, since I didn't use it at all...